# Prove Pythagoras theorem through dimensional analysis

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, physics

I've recently become acquainted with [Buckingham's Pi theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buckingham_pi_theorem) for the first time . Then I've found an excercise that says:

Use dimensional analysis to prove the Pythagoras theorem. [Hint: Drop a perpendicular to the hypotenuse of a right-angle triangle and consider the resulting similar triangles.]

Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: it's a rather well known proof: the perpendicular divides the triangle to 2 triangles, and they are all similar (having two equal angles); the sum of the areas of the small triangles is equal to the area of the original triangle; the area of the square over a side of the original triangle is a constant times the area of one of the 3 triangles (of the one whose hypotenuse is the chosen side)

Comment: @user8268: and this qualifies as a proof by dimensional analysis?

Comment: well, hardly:)  I guess the fact that the area of a right-angle triangle is a constant times hypotenuse${}^2$ (where the constant is a constant if we only consider similar triangles) can be seen as dimensional analysis.

Comment: I like to call this the one-line proof of the Pythagoras Theorem, the one line being the perpendicular to the hypotenuse.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is one formulation of this argument; it is the same as the one suggested by user8268 in the above comments, but perhaps this formulation will make it clearer why this is a proof by dimensional analysis:

- You want to prove that the sum of the squares on each of the non-hypotenuse sides equals
  the square on the hypotenuse.
- You generalize, and instead prove that for *any* shape, if you scale it by $a$, and then by $b$, the sum of the resulting areas is the area of the shape scaled by $c$.  (We began with the case of the unit square.)
- By thinking about how areas scale,
  it suffices to check for one particular shape.
- We check it by taking the shape to be the original triangle (to be pedantic: scaled so that its hypotenuse has length one).  This case is clear: just drop a perpendicular from the vertex opposite the
  hypotenuse to the hypotenuse, and see note that the triangle with hypotenuse length $c$
  is the sum of two similar triangle of hypotenuse lengths $a$ and $b$.

The dimensional analysis is in the third step.   The point is in the final
equality that is proved, i.e. in the final proof of $a^2 + b^2 = c^2$,
these quantities are *not* the area of any particular shape, but rather
are the scaling factors for the areas of the original triangle after scaling
its lengths by $a$, $b$, and $c$.  This is *why* it is a proof by dimensional analysis.

[I originally posted this [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/40337/ingenuity-in-mathematics/40411#40411), and you can see the comments there for some historical background on this particular argument.]

Answer (score 2):

I recently came across a proof of Pythagoras Theorem via dimensional analysis in a book by Paul J Nahin called Mrs. Perkins's Electric Quilt, which goes as follows.

Let there be a right triangle with sides $a, b, c$, with $c$ the hypotenuse and let $\phi$ be one acute angle of this triangle. Since area has dimensions of length squared, and given $c, \phi$ we can uniquely determine the triangle, the area must be $$\Delta = c^2 f(\phi)$$
Now, drop the altitude on $c$. We get two right triangles with hypotenuses $a, b$ and one acute angle $\phi$. Hence, there areas are $$\Delta_1 = a^2 f(\phi) \qquad \Delta_2 = b^2 f(\phi)$$
But, $$\Delta = \Delta_1 + \Delta_2 \implies c^2 f(\phi) = a^2 f(\phi) + b^2 f(\phi)$$
$$\implies \boxed{c^2 = a^2 + b^2}$$