# A didactic proof of the Pythagorean Theorem?

Tags: geometry, proof-writing, triangles, education, plane-geometry

Does the following provide a didactically sound approach to the Pythagorean Theorem? We first consider the hypotenuse of a right isosceles triangle and then we extend the idea to a general right triangle.

---

Let us consider a right isosceles triangle that has the side length $a$ and hypotenuse $c$. The Pythagorean theorem states that $2a^2 = c^2$. To see this, we divide the area of a square into two right triangles: $$a^2 = \frac{1}{2}c\cdot \frac{c}{2}+ \frac{1}{2}c\cdot \frac{c}{2}.$$
[image]

Next we consider a right triangle that has the side lengths $a,b$ and hypotenuse $c$. Here we divide the area of a rectangle into three right triangles:

$$ab = \frac{1}{2}ab + \frac{1}{2}(c-Y)X + \frac{1}{2}XY,$$

where $a/b = X/(c-Y)$ and $a/b = Y/X$ are deduced from the similar triangles. Thus, we have $ab =cX=(abc^2)/(a^2+b^2)$, i.e., the general Pythagorean theorem $a^2+b^2 = c^2$.

[image]

Comment: I wonder whether you can define those trigonometric functions and prove that they have the required properties, without at any point making use of the Pythagorean theorem.  From a didactic point of view, it seems like a disaster, because the proof is directed to a student who knows trigonometry but not how to prove the Pythagorean theorem, and I don't think such a student exists.

Comment: @MJD I changed to the similarity argument.

Comment: @Hulkster Proof looks fine to me. Not too different from the similarity arguments used [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1310/291201) or [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/53167/291201), only presented in terms of area rather than lengths.